# How to highlight a row in QTableWidget?

Tags: qt

I'm having a `QTableWidget` with 9000 data. I can search data from the table, like, if I search for '10', whole data starting with '10' will be displayed.
Now I need to highlight the first row, since it shows the accurate search result.

I'm using:

```
ui->tableWidget->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
```

for highlighting the selected row.

How can I highlight the first row of table?

Answer (score 16):

I am not sure I am clear of why you need to set selection behavior unless you are planning for the user to be able to do the selection by clicking on the cells.  And if you want that to be the default behavior then just set this as a property of the `tableWidget` when you use the QT `designer`.

But you can certainly do:

```
ui->tableWidget->selectRow(0);
```

That will highlight the row.